# Package for tune function in r?

Tags: r

I am trying to use the tune() for cross validation in r. But I am getting an error that could not find function tune. Is there any specific package I need to install?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `tune` function comes from the package `e1071`.

Answer (score 1):

For any specific function you want to find the package, you can use the `findFn()` function from the `sos` package.

```
library(sos)
findFn('tune', maxPages = 1)
```